# How to use Image to link to a Self-hosted Video?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I'm trying to use an image to link to a video which we host. But when I click the image link and the new window opens, the browser (Chrome) asks to download the video instead of playing it.

My code:

```
<a href="video/BlueRidge-medium.mp4" type="video/mp4" target="new" >
<img src="ProjGalleries/BlueRidgeCC/brcc-play.png" >
</a>
```

Using absolute vs. relative paths has had no effect. What can I do to get the video to play in the new window?

Comment: Well, you're linking them to the video file.  You'll need a page that embeds videos in an HTML <Video> element or something similar.

Comment: Linking directly to the video file is fine as long as the server provides the correct `Content-Type` header for that file type.

Answer (score 2):

This issue probably arises from the `Content-Type` header supplied by your server for that file type.

- `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` will trigger a file download
- `Content-Type: video/mp4` will play in the browser

Check your response headers for the request to `video/BlueRidge-medium.mp4`, and then configure your server to supply the correct `Content-Type` header for your desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you, @simmer, that worked! Got my IT dept to change the settings and it works perfectly.